# Can the text be formatted to appear in a more appealing way while using a receipt card?

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using a receipt card in one of my projects and I have been trying to format my subtitle text using `\n`, `\t`, `\r\n`, but none of these seem to give the expected output.
Is there another way to format the text?

Comment: How about showing an example of the text, how you want it formatted, what you've tried, and how it's not what you want??

Answer (score 0):

The receipt card is a predefined card template that is not designed for customization.

If you want to create custom card layouts, use Adaptive Cards.

- Overview: http://adaptivecards.io/
- Examples: http://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/index.html?hostApp=WebChat%20(Bot%20Framework)
- Code sample for .NET SDK: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-AdaptiveCards
- Walk-through blog article: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/07/Adaptive-Card-Dotnet/